# Can't play you tube video in android

Tags: android, youtube

I am not able to play you tube video directly by calling the URL from application. This is my code

```
   play_Youtube.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {         
        public void onClick(View v) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            mc.setAnchorView(videoView);
            mc.setMediaPlayer(videoView);
            videoView.setMediaController(mc);
            videoView.setKeepScreenOn(true);
            videoView.setVideoPath("http://www.veoh.com/watch/v2000579385DSyC7f?h1=thailand-crown-prince-dog-birthday.mpeg");
            videoView.start();
        }
    });
```

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4880379/android-mediaplayer-throws-an-error-while-playing-a-youtube-video-with-video-vie use this link..

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
startActivity(new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW, Uri.parse("http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=cxLG2wtE7TM")));
```